# ARKit object randomly wiggles

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, scenekit, arkit

In our arkit project, the object starts to wiggle. We tried to use older code, which worked well before we had this issue, but it the wiggling doesn't stop.
We enabled the debug option to show the origin, which wiggles aswell. We tried using our app with different devices(iphone XS, Ipad pro 2018, ipad 2018, all with ios 12.1.3) and objects.
The tracking image has the right size.

This is our configuration(Swift):

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    guard let referenceImages = ARReferenceImage.referenceImages(inGroupNamed: "Photos", bundle: Bundle.main) else { return }
    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    configuration.detectionImages = referenceImages
    configuration.maximumNumberOfTrackedImages = 2
    let options: ARSession.RunOptions = [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors]
    sceneView.session.run(configuration, options: options)
    sceneView.delegate = self
}
```

This is our renderer:

```
 func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
        guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else { return }
        let referenceImage = imageAnchor.referenceImage
        let imageName = referenceImage.name ?? "no name"


        let plane = SCNPlane(width: referenceImage.physicalSize.width, height: referenceImage.physicalSize.height)
        let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
        plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0) //make the plane invisable

        let obj = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/obj.scn")!
        let objNode = obj.rootNode.childNodes.first!
        objNode.position = SCNVector3Zero
        objNode.eulerAngles.y = 90
        planeNode.addChildNode(objNode)
        node.addChildNode(planeNode)
    }
```

Can anyone help to stop the wiggling?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that: "World tracking is an inexact science. This process can often produce impressive accuracy, leading to realistic AR experiences. However, it relies on details of the device’s physical environment that are not always consistent or are difficult to measure in real time without some degree of error. To build high-quality AR experiences, be aware of these caveats and tips". 
From

> From [Understanding World Tracking in ARKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/understanding_world_tracking_in_arkit).

To get better AR experience, provide your app with appropriate physical environment with good lighting, textured floor etc...
Hope it helps!